# What is missing from this delete process node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

The edit works fine, but it seems fundamentally different from the delete since the edit actually goes to a different page. This is part of a project where we're kinda just piecing together code that was given to us and adding a few lines here and there, but I don't know what is missing from the delete.

The request gets the item id, the query looks like a correct delete function to me, and the rest is just printing results? The delete button works, but that's all i can see.

[image]
[image]

delete--

```
app.delete('/delete/(:id)', function(req, res, next) {
    req.getConnection(function(error, conn) {
        conn.query('DELETE from store where id = ' + req.params.id, function(err, result) {

            if (rows.length <= 0) {
                req.flash('error', err)
                // redirect to users list page
                res.redirect('/store')
            } else {
                req.flash('success',

                    )
                // redirect to users list page
                res.redirect('/store')
            }
        })
    })
})
```

edit--

```
app.get('/edit/(:id)', function(req, res, next) {

    req.getConnection(function(error, conn) {
        conn.query( 
            'SELECT * From store Where id = ' + req.params.id, function(err, rows, field) {
            // if item not found
            if (rows.length <= 0) {
                req.flash('error', 'Item not found with id = ' +
                    id )
                res.redirect('store/edit')
            } else { // if item found
                // render to views/store/edit.ejs template file
                res.render( 'store/edit' , {
                    title: 'Edit Item',

                    id: req.params.id,
                    qty:rows[0].qty ,
                    price: rows[0].price,
                    sname: rows[0].sname
                })
            }
        })
    })
})


app.put('/edit/(:id)', function(req, res, next) {
    req.assert('sname', 'Name is required').notEmpty()
    //Validate name
    req.assert('qty', 'Quantity is required').notEmpty()
    //Validate qty
    req.assert('price', 'Price is required').notEmpty()
    //Validate price
    var errors = req.validationErrors()
    if (!errors) { //No errors were found. Passed Validation!

    var item = {
        sname: req.sanitize('sname').escape().trim(),
        qty: req.sanitize('qty').escape().trim(),
        price: req.sanitize('price').escape().trim()
    }

        req.getConnection(function(error, conn) {
            conn.query('Update store set ? where id =' + req.params.id, item, function(err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    req.flash('error', err)
                    // render to views/store/edit.ejs
                    res.render('store/edit', {
                        id: req.params.id,
                        sname: item.sname,
                        qty: item.qty,
                        price: item.price
                    })

                } else {
                    req.flash('success', 'Data updated successfully!')
                    // render to views/store/edit.ejs
                    res.render('store/edit', {
                        title: 'Edit Item',
                        id: req.params.id,
                        sname: item.sname,
                        qty: item.qty,
                        price: item.price
                    })
                }
            })
        })

    }
    else {
        var error_msg = ''
        errors.forEach(function(error) {
            error_msg += error.msg + '<br>'
        })
        req.flash('error', error_msg)

        res.render( '/store/edit', {
            title: 'Edit Item,',
            id: req.params.id,
            sname: req.body.sname,
            qty: req.body.qty,
            price: req.body.price ,
        })
    }
})
```

form content--

```
<form method="post" action="/store/delete/<%= item.id %>"
        style="float:right">
        </form>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value='Delete'
        onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"
```

Comment: this code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use prepared statements with something like knex.js

Comment: It's not real, just an offline project for a class to get us aware of nodejs

Comment: ok, related to your question though, we'll need to see the code making the call to the endpoint. I also recommend opening the chrome/ie/firefox devtools (network tab) while you click delete to see what's actually sent - for example, what if id is not a number?

Comment: @Catalyst you mean the ejs file? I posted it

Comment: I guess I missed it - still though, are you sure `% item.id %` holds the right kind of value? In the network call did you see the right id being passed?

Comment: Nothing is actually registering in the network tag. Edit process does show a POST but delete doesn't do anything.

Comment: @grilam14 Your attitude towards your project is troublesome.  You realize that it isn't just about security, it's about a proper working solution?  Fix your code.  Use prepared/parameterized statements.  If you don't care about the fundamentals of a CRUD application, why should we care to help you?

Comment: @Brad I guess I can care more about security when I actually can wrap my head around the basics of a delete

Comment: @grilam14 Read my comment again.  This isn't just about security, this is about a bug you have in your code.  You **cannot** reliably just stick data from one context into another.  This sort of situation *will* break on you some day, even with normal operations.  Suppose you want to use a field with a quote mark in it or something.  That's not an attack, but your code will break.  Learn to query a database properly.  And, anyone who told you to simply concatenate variables into an SQL query is flat wrong.  If that's what you're learning in school... question everything else they taught you.

Comment: @grilam14 Additionally, you're actively making this harder on yourself by not using parameterized queries, which are actually easier to work with than concatenating data.

Comment: @Brad this isn't a node.js class. The point of this project was to show us in the simplest way how this stuff works. We don't know parameterized queries, just the most basic mysql. If this were a class that was actually dedicated to this type of technology we'd probably do it the right way.

Comment: @grilam14 What you were shown isn't the simplest way.  What I'm telling you applies generically, to any application using any SQL database.  What I'm telling you isn't some sort of advanced way of doing something... it's simply the *right* way, and you were clearly shown a *wrong* way.  for your own sake, do some reading on the topic and seriously consider whether or not the people teaching the class have any clue what they're talking about.  This is a serious bug with serious implications for anything you build in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="POST">` sends a `POST` request, not a `DELETE` HTTP request.

HTML forms can only do `action="POST"` or `action="GET"`. You need to either:

- Use `POST` for deletes in this case.
- Use javascript to do the `DELETE` request. (ajax-ish request)

Answer (score 0):

I guess your form for `delete` is getting closed before your input values.

Change the html as follow:

```
<form method="post" action="/store/delete/<%= item.id %>"
    style="float:right">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value='Delete'
    onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE"/>
 </form>
```